# Why would Python's variable length arguments be used over passing in a list/dictionary?

Tags: python, coding-style, variadic-functions

Python allows you to declare a function like

```
def print_all(*arguments):
    for a in arguments:
        print(a)
print_all(1,2,3)
```

Which allows one to pass in a variable amount of data. This seems much less readable to me than building a list or a dictionary, and passing those in as arguments like so.

```
def print_all2(things_to_print):
    for thing in things_to_print:
        print(thing)
things_to_print = [1,2,3]
print_all2(things_to_print)
```

The second option allows you to give the argument a proper name. When would it be preferable to use the *arguments technique? Is there a time when using *arguments is more Pythonic?

Comment: You misunderstand the usage of the `*`. It is used for taking in an arbitrary _number of arguments_. Your two functions do the same thing because you unpack twice in the former.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very opinion based, but sometimes you want to use a function providing the arguments in-line. It just looks a bit clearer:

```
function("please", 0, "work this time", 2.3)
```

than:

```
function(["please", 0, "work this time", 2.3])
```

In fact, there is a good example, which you even mention in your question: `print`! Imagine you'd have to create a list each time you wanted to print something:

```
print(["please print my variable", x, " and another:", y])
print([x])
```

Tedious.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a time when using *arguments is more Pythonic?

Not only "more pythonic", but it's often **necessary**.

Your *need* to use `*args` whenever you don't know how many arguments a function will recieve.

Think, for example, about decorators:

```
def deco(fun):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       do_stuff()
       return fun(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Nice example! Definitely better than mine.